# About $l_2$ and $l_\infty$ Norms

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

There is a theorem about norms that says $$||\textbf{x}||_\infty\le||\textbf{x}||_2\le\sqrt{n}||\textbf{x}||_\infty$$

In a text I found an illustration of this.

[image]

How does it correspond to the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The illustration shows that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the Euclidean unit ball, i.e., the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|x\|_2\leq 1\}$ is contained in the unit square, i.e. the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|x\|_{\infty}\leq 1\}$. So if $\|x\|_2\leq 1 $ then $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq 1$, which implies of course that $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_2$ for every $x$, because given any $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $x\neq 0$, the point $x/\|x\|_2$ belongs to the Euclidean unit ball, hence also to the unit square, hence $\|x/\|x\|_2\|_{\infty}\leq 1$, hence $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_2$.

It also shows that if you dilate the unit square by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$, then the inclusion is reversed, that is, the set $\{x:\|x\|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$ is contained in the Euclidean unit ball, which of course implies that $\|x\|_2\leq\sqrt{2}\|x\|_{\infty}$ for every $x$, the proof being very similar to the one above.

The next step is to generalize this to higher dimensions. And so it happens, that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the inequalities you wrote
$$\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_2\leq\sqrt{n}\|x\|_{\infty}$$
are valid. This is because the Euclidean ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|_2\leq 1\}$ is contained in the unit cube, i.e, the set
$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|_{\infty}\leq 1\}$. (prove it!) and if you dilate the unit cube by a factor of $\sqrt{n}$, you get the reverse inclusion. To see this, note simply that
$$x_1^2+\cdots + x_n^2\leq n\max_i x_i^2$$
hence $\|x\|_2\leq\sqrt{n}\|x\|_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that every norm satisfies $\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha| \|x\|$ (absolute homogeneous property).
Hence in order to show that $\|x\|_1 \ge \|x\|_2$ (with $\| \cdot \|_1$ and ,$\| \cdot \|_2$ two norms) , it is enough to show that the boundary of the unit ball for the first norm is inside the unit ball of the second one.

In other words : let $B_1,B_2$ the unit balls for $\| \cdot \|_1,\| \cdot \|_2$ respectively. If $\partial B_1 \subset B_2$, then $\|x\|_1 \ge \|x\|_2$.

Indeed, if $\partial B_1 \subset B_2$ :

$$\forall x, \|x\|_1=1 \implies \|x\|_2 \le 1 \implies \|x\|_2  \le\|x\|_1.$$

Now, being given any $x$. We have $\frac x {\|x\|_1} \in \partial B_1$ which implies $\left|\left|{\frac x {\|x\|_1}} \right| \right|_2 \le \left|\left|{\frac x {\|x\|_1}} \right| \right|_1$.

Thus, by absolute homogeneous :

$$\|x\|_2  \le\|x\|_1.$$

Remark : if $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm and $K>0$, then $K \| \cdot \|$ is also a norm.

Comment: Great answer! Have you thought of changing your 1s to infinities in those norms just to be consistent with the question for future readers? Should just be backslash infty in TeX.

Also just out of curiosity, where (which textbooks or authors or articles, if you have any on hand like an intro text to topology or wherever) are you finding this terminology of "absolute homogeneity"? I've never seen that term for that property before and like the sound of it!

Comment: It is absolute homogeneous that I had in mind in fact, sorry (English is not my native language). @TannerStrunk

Comment: Oh no problem! I am just curious where that terminology is used as I have not seen it before.

Comment: You can find it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition

Comment: Ooooh like homogeneous for an arbitrary function with inputs from a vector space! That makes more sense now! (Interestingly, the reference for that on Wiki is for something about quantum mechanics in Hilbert space.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every point $x$ on the circle falls inside the outer square, which means that $\|x\|_\infty \leq 1 \implies \|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2$.

Also, every point $x$ on the circle falls outside the inner square, which means that $\|x\|_\infty \geq 1/\sqrt{n} \implies \sqrt{n} \|x \|_\infty \geq \| x \|_2$.

If these inequalities are true for vectors $x$ that satisfy $\|x\|_2 = 1$, then it follows that the inequalities are true for all vectors.